# python - matplotlib plt.plot parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib

HI  i am python beginner

I just practice scikit-learn this topic

[Test with permutations the significance of a classification score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_permutation_test_for_classification.html)

I was confused about this matplotlib plot method

```
plt.hist(permutation_scores, 20, label='Permutation scores',edgecolor='black')
ylim = plt.ylim()
plt.plot(2 * [score], ylim, '--g', linewidth=3,label='Classification Score'' (pvalue %s)' % pvalue)
plt.plot(2 * [1. / n_classes], ylim, '--k', linewidth=3, label='Luck')
plt.ylim(ylim)
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.show()
```

here why use 2 * [score] rather then 2 * score

if i use 2*score then figure cannot display correctly

```
plt.plot(2 * [score], ylim, '--g', linewidth=3,label='Classification Score'' (pvalue %s)' % pvalue)
```

2 * [score] = [0.51333333333333331, 0.51333333333333331]

but if i draw a 2-d plot
the x should be 1 number ?
and i wrong?

Comment: `2*[score]`, as you showed, creates a list of length 2, let's call this x. `x =
 [score, score]`. `ylim` is also a list of length 2, the min and max on the yaxis, so let's say `ylim = [ymin, ymax]`. So this code should plot a line between the points `(score, ymin)` to `(score, ymax)`.

Comment: WOW! thanks for your explanation, now i know why use 2*[score] !!!